# CSS auto expand header and footer div width to match content div width, when content goes extra wide (beyond screen)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a web site layout with header, content and footer.
Both header and footer should expand to 100% width. And they do. But when I put a very wide element inside content div, header and footer stay at width of my screen and do not expand further to match content width. Please help to achieve such behaviour.

In my example below, I would like blue header and yellow footer to expand and match width of gray content (which in real life will contain a table with unknown width)

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/StormBlast/z4hegp1o/3/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="content">
        <div style="width: 2500px; background-color: gray;">
            here comes very wide table with some results and expands beyond screen borders (in width) 
            here comes very wide table with some results and expands beyond screen borders (in width) 
            here comes very wide table with some results and expands beyond screen borders (in width) 
            here comes very wide table with some results and expands beyond screen borders (in width) 
            here comes very wide table with some results and expands beyond screen borders (in width) 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    padding:10px;
    background:#5ee;
}
#content {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:80px;   /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#ee5;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try using jQuery for this kind of size-matching.

With jQuery you simply grab the width of the content div, and change both the header and footer widths just when the page is loaded.

```
    $('#header,#footer').width($('#content div').width());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z4hegp1o/4/

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it works. I will definitely go that way if there is no other way to achieve it with CSS and HTML only. I know that using tables for main layout would work, but it is even worse than JS.

Comment: I am afraid that it won't just work like that with JS. I will never know what is the structure of html inside content div. There will be sub apps loaded in it. I would have to iterate through whole DOM tree inside the content to find max width and then set it to header and footer. I can do it naturally, but now my motivation to try to achieve it via pure CSS and HTML is even bigger.

Comment: I changed strategy - I no longer want to resize header and footer. They will always stay at 100% screen width with position: absolute; and will travel while scrolling: $(window).scroll(function(){ $('#header, #footer').css({'left': $(this).scrollLeft()});});