# Expand element widths to match expanded screen width

Tags: css

A [question was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25224405/css-auto-expand-header-and-footer-div-width-to-match-content-div-width-when-con) a few years ago whereby if an element's width is larger than the screen width, then other block elements (h1 etc.) do not expand to match ([see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bq2vgtbb/4/) whereby the h1 width does not change after the wide element appears):

```js
function addElement(){
    $("#para").after('<div class="wide">Wide</div>');
    $("a").fadeOut();
    // $("h1").width($(".wide").width()); // <-- trying to avoid needing this
}
```

```css
body {margin:0; padding:0}
h1 {background-color:#eee}
.wide {background-color:#00c; color:#fff; width:110%; margin-top:1em; margin-bottom:1em}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Header 1</h1>
<p id="para">
    <a href="#" onclick="addElement(); return false;">Add wide element</a>
</p>
```

Although the original answer *did* work, now that CSS3 is more mainstream, I wondered whether there was any smarter way to accomplish the goal, without resizing manually using JQuery?  For example, is there a pure CSS solution?  I do not know the width of the element in advance (its a table of data from an ERP system and sometimes can be very wide).

If not, I'm happy to delete the question, but couldn't think of a way to draw attention back to an older problem whereby a better solution may now exist.

Comment: How about offering a bounty on the other question?

Comment: An easy CSS only solution might be possible once CSS4 hits http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-selectors4-20110929/#subject. Unfortunately I don't think any current browsers support this type of parent selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `body` and its block elements expanded to match `.wide`'s width, then `.wide` would no longer be 110%.  That's really the crux of the problem.

The easiest solution may be to set the widths of both `body` *and* `.wide` in pixels, after `.wide` has been added to the DOM.

```js
function addElement(){
  $("#para").after('<div class="wide">Wide</div>');
  $("a").fadeOut();
  $('body, .wide').width($('.wide').width());
}
```

```css
body {margin:0; padding:0;}

h1 {background-color:#eee;}

.wide {background-color:#00c; color:#fff; width:110%; margin-top:1em; margin-bottom:1em}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Header 1</h1>
<p id="para">
    <a href="#" onclick="addElement(); return false;">Add wide element</a>
</p>
```

Comment: That's very neat, thanks.  I didn't even know VW units existed until I read up on your code!

Comment: Oh my gosh, the `vw` was left over from an earlier attempt, and I wasn't even using it in my final code.  Now edited.  (But I'm glad you've discovered `vw` units!)

Comment: Strange question, but why doesn't this work as an alternative: `$('body').width($('.wide').width());`.  I can't figure why I need to set the width of `.wide` to itself, *as well as* setting the `body` width.

Comment: The `width()` method sets the width in pixels.  If you don't set the width of `.wide`, it will stay at 110%.  So when `body` widens to match its width, `.wide` will grow again to remain 10% wider than `body`.

Comment: Facepalm!  Yes, of course it would - that makes perfect sense!  Thank you :-)

Comment: My original explanation left much to be desired.  I've now updated it to explicitly mention that the code sets the width in pixels.

Answer (score 3):

What I think you want is to set the width of the parent object of `.wide`, and have the children of that parent affect the width of all of its children.

I decided to change it so instead of your new element having the class `wide`, I gave that class to its parent (`body` in this case) because css doesn't have a parent selector, so this seemed like the simplest solution.

```js
function addElement(){
    $("#para").after('<div class="foo">Wide</div>'); // <-- updated
    $("a").fadeOut();
    $("body").addClass("wide"); // <-- new
}
```

```css
body {margin:0; padding:0}
h1 {background-color:#eee; width: 100%;}
.foo {background-color:#00c; color:#fff; margin-top:1em; margin-bottom:1em} // <-- updated
.wide { width: 110%; } // <-- new
.wide > * { width: auto; } // <-- new
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Header 1</h1>
<p id="para">
    <a href="#" onclick="addElement(); return false;">Add wide element</a>
</p>
```

It is slightly different from how you doing things, but I think that it should accomplish what you are trying to do

Update:

Instead of

```
$("body").addClass("wide");
```

adding

```
$("#para").parent().addClass("wide");
$("#para").parent().width($("#para").parent().width()*1.1);
```

should work with the tables, but I'm not sure if you'll find this any better than

```
$("h1").width($(".wide").width());
```

which you were trying to avoid.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DeadEli/cu9r86m4/)

Comment: That's quite neat.  The only catch is that I don't know the width in advance (the element is a table of data from an ERP system, which sometimes can be huge)

Answer (score 1):

It could work if you set the `body` and the wide block style as follows. It is the only **pure CSS** solution that I can think of.

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kv2b8aek/)**</kbd>

```js
function addElement() {
    $("#para").after('<div class="wide">Wide</div>');
    $("a").fadeOut();
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block; /*key*/
    min-width: 100%; /*key*/
}
h1 {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.wide {
    background-color: #00c;
    color: #fff;
    min-width: 1000px; /*percentage won't work, but vw works i.e. 110vw */
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Header 1</h1>
<p id="para">
    <a href="#" onclick="addElement(); return false;">Add wide element</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Apologies i have been working away all week.  I like this, but setting body to inline-block doesn't feel right for some reason (strictly IMHO).  However, it does allow to not know the width in advance, which is good, however, I wasn't demanding a *pure* CSS solution, just wondering *if* one existed, or any modern approach.  Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As you know the width for your wide element (in this case 110%), you could just define your css 'wide'-class for body, instead of for the inserted element, like this:

```
body { margin:0; padding:0 }
body.wide { width:110%; } //<<< new
h1 { background-color:#eee; }
div { background-color:#00c; color:#fff; margin-top:1em; margin-bottom:1em; }
```

... and then simplyfy your JS to the following:

```
function addElement(){
    $('body').addClass('wide').find("#para").after('<div>Wide</div>');
    $("a").fadeOut();
}
```

... off course, when you remove the inserted element from dom, you must also remove the 'wide'-class from body.